# JdbcBatchItemWriter stored procedure call is not being invoked

Tags: jdbc, spring-batch

I am trying to call stored procedure in the spring batch project, stored procedure has an update when spring batch runs neither the updated record appears in database nor the exception occurs.

I have verified the flow of spring batch writer configured accordingly

```
@Bean
ItemWriter<EPCAddress> mdmAddrItemWriter(DataSource dataSource, 
   NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {

     System.out.println("mdmAddrItemWriter...");
     JdbcBatchItemWriter<EPCAddress> writer = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<EPCAddress>();
     try {

            writer.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<EPCAddress>());
            writer.setSql("CALL TEMP_STREET_ADDR_STANDR_PROC (:addr_ln_1_txt,:city_name,:teritry_id,:postl_cd_num,:loctr_id)");
            writer.setDataSource(dataSource);
            writer.setAssertUpdates(false);

    System.out.println("After paramProvider...");
    System.out.println("databaseItemWriter="+writer.toString());
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    return writer;
}
```

Is there any way to debug if the stored procedure is actually being called??

Answer (score -1):

There was a problem with stored procedure. After updating with simple statement, it worked fine.